# What is the most efficient way to get a value by ObjectId in MongoDB using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
db.test.find_one(ObjectId('4f3dd96d1453373bcb000000'))
```

or something else entirely?  I know that the _id column is indexed automatically and am hoping to capitalize on that efficiency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach is correct.

Since you're asking about efficiency, remember that when you're optimizing read operations for performance, you may want to read only the attributes that you need. If certain attributes of your documents are large, then this can reduce the IO costs (transferring data from server to client) dramatically. For example, if your document has 20 attributes, but you're only using 5 of them, then don't pull the other 15 over the wire. In pymongo, you can do this using the optional `fields` parameter of the `collection.find` function. Obviously you need to balance performance vs code maintainability here, since listing attributes increases maintenance costs.

More optimization suggestions are available in [the official docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization). Their list includes "Optimization #3: Select only relevant fields" which is just the point that I made above.

Comment: Can you expound on this point a bit--pulling backing attributes that one cares about?

Comment: Expounded. This can make your code a little more verbose, so don't bother if you're just going to save a few bytes here and there. But if you have very large attributes, and sometimes you don't need them, then the savings might add up. Depends on your data and on the performance requirements on your application.

Comment: Thanks; are these gains in terms of how much memory mongodb is using?

Comment: No, mongodb would already have all of the attributes in memory. I meant to point out that there would be lower network overhead due to fewer bytes being sent server-to-client. In addition, you're right that the python client/script would use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a value specifically by the _id, then I would say yes this is the most efficient approach.

Depending on your data, it may be more efficient to index that value and search on it.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the _id than you should call in that way only. `db.test.find_one(ObjectId('4f3dd96d1453373bcb000000'))`
You full code in pymongo may be like this

```
connection=Connection(self.host ) #%(self.user_name,self.password))
    #connection1=Connection(host=self.host, port=self.port)
    db=connection[self.db_name]
    db.authenticate(self.user_name, self.password)
    collection=db[self.question_collection]
    obj_id= ObjectId(_id)
    info=collection.find_one(obj_id)
```